# Pandas rolling window on a dataframe with a string-type column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'sensor1': [1.4, 1, 0.5, 1, 3 ], 'sensor2': [1.2, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 4 ], 'label':["a", "a", "b", "b", "c" ]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

As you can see, I have 2 columns with sensor values and another column with the corresponding labels. Now, based on that, I want to create another dataframe in which I have the means of the sensor observations for a window of length 3.
In order to achieve this, I applied pandas rolling window function by calling:
`df_mean = df.rolling(3).mean()`

```
sensor1         sensor2
0   NaN           NaN
1   NaN           NaN
2   0.966667    1.066667
3   0.833333    1.000000
4   1.500000    1.833333
```

I want, however, to preserve the labels. For each window of 3 the label will be the most frequently occurring one. Any ideas how to achieve this so that I have the same columns in the dataframe as in the beginning but with the new mean values and the corresponding labels (the most frequent label in a window) ?
I saw that encoding the labels as integer numbers 1 - 3 will let me use  for instance:

`df_labels = df["label"].rolling(window = 3).apply(lambda x: x.mode()[0])`

which will provide me with the correct labels (but, of course, encoded) and then I will have to merge both dataframes to achieve my goal.
However, is there another way to achieve it without encoding the strings?

The final output I want is (given the example above and a rolling window of length 3):

```
sensor1     sensor2     label
0   NaN           NaN         NaN
1   NaN           NaN         NaN
2   0.966667    1.066667       a
3   0.833333    1.000000       b
4   1.500000    1.833333       b
```

Comment: `rolling` doesn't work on strings, so what you're doing is probably the best approach

Comment: I saw that I can use apply() in a rolling function, but I am not sure if it works with strings.

Comment: It doesn't. Still throws `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`.

Comment: could you post your code? let's see if we can improve it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatize things, you could use `select_dtypes`:

```
df2 = (df
 .select_dtypes('number')
 .rolling(3).mean()
 .join(df.select_dtypes(exclude='number'))
)
```

output:

```
    sensor1   sensor2 label
0       NaN       NaN     a
1       NaN       NaN     a
2  0.966667  1.066667     b
3  0.833333  1.000000     b
4  1.500000  1.833333     c
```

Comment: I think OP wants the label column to yield `a` for row `2` because within the rolling window it is the mode rather than just joining them across indicies.